# How to write an automatically startup file script to edit /etc/profile

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to change some line of code in **PATH:home/etc/profile**

It is easy to modify manually[ROOT PERMISSION] How can i change using my own script without touching profile file manually

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your script while root, the script will have root permissions, and will be able to change that file.

edit: here is a better way to do it (look for the visudo answer) : https://askubuntu.com/questions/209714/adding-root-privileges-to-a-bash-script